# Why is it only possible to build a homeomorphism rather than a diffeomorphism in Hartman-Grobman Theorem"

Tags: differential-topology, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

It is emphasized in all the materials that I have seen about Hartman-Grobman theorem (including [textbooks](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-5703-5) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem)) that the topological conjugacy is only a homeomorphism but not diffeomorphism, i.e., it can only be a $C^0$, not $C^1$. So ... why? **Is there an example that a $C^0$ homeomorphism is the best thing we can have, and a diffeomorphism can never become a topological conjugacy?**

Also, can this map be differentiable or smooth except at the fixed point (i.e. the zero point of the linearized vector field)?

Comment: See this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36795/local-linearization-of-ode-at-singular-point